# ExtJs versions working toghether

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a big web application working with ExtJs 3.4 and I want to upgrade to ExtJs 4.2.1 but I will do it by modules. Is there any problem if i have working both ExtJs versions working toghether?

Thanks!

Comment: A little Googling for [extjs upgrade 3 to 4](https://www.google.com/search?q=extjs+upgrade+3+to+4&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) would have been a good place to start. Sencha even has a blog post: [Ext JS 3 to 4 Migration](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/).

Comment: Look at the example: `Ext JS 3 Desktop + Ext JS 4 Charts`: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/sandbox/sandbox.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, very useful information and now i have an idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I will suggest this is a bad idea.

As the comments to the OP point out, it can be done... however I won't say that it's anywhere near as easy as that guide suggests.

More importantly, you're upgrading to a version (4.2.1) which is more than two years old and NOT the most recent version of that release version (4.2.3). You will also find it difficult to utilize Sencha Cmd in its current form, if that's a concern for you (it should be).

Sencha is set to release Ext JS 6.0 any day now -- so perhaps it would make the most sense to migrate your 3.x code (incompatible with 4.x anyhow) to a more recent version (5.1.x or just wait for 6.0.x).